# Discrete Mathematics, Modus Tollens Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

[image: Question pic]

So in this picture we have two rows. The first row is a famous logic implication law by the name Modus Tollens. I am asking this question to this honorable forum because someone I know said that we could use (p<-->q) instead of (p-->q) and get the same result in the RHS of the expression. So basically row 2 is also a law of Modus Tollens. This made me confused because I know that (p<-->q) is not logically equivalent to (p-->q). My question, is am I wrong or am I right and if I'm wrong, why is that the case?

Comment: $P \iff Q$ is "stronger" because it contains $P \rightarrow Q$ [[ AND $Q \rightarrow P$ ]] , thus it eventually becomes MODUS TOLLENS to give us that Conclusion

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I am seeing different things here and I am still confused unfortunately. Is the second expression true or not (is row 1 the same as row 2), thats basically what I am asking.

Comment: They are not the same but they are both valid.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid principles.

But they are not the same. The first one is Modus Tollens. The second one is very much related to Modus Tollens ... but is something different. I actually don't know of any name it has.